# How to detect download and upload speed with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, performance, connection

I am looking to create a relatively simple connection speed test wherein the user clicks a button and we have them download a few files, and then once that is done, we then initiate an upload back to us.

I have a seen a lot of various answers and methods for doing this with Javascript, JQuery, etc.  What is the best way to accomplish the goal?  I am fairly new to Javascript and web programming in general.

Comment: Ive looked into HTML5, Javascript.....I am just a tad confused.  I currently have a Perl CGI script that calls a Javascript to do the work, and within that script, i'd like to initiate the download(s), time them, and then do the same with the uploads, while also attaining user information (IP, hostname, as much as I can get since it is for internal customers only).

Comment: In my opinion I think Chris Van has done a great work with [JSBandwidth](https://code.google.com/p/jsbandwidth/).

Comment: Thanks for the advice.  It looks good, though when I run it, I keep getting a download speed of infinity.  Any thoughts?

Comment: It immediately falls into the success area and the start and end times are equal.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use LogNormal's version of boomerang.js - https://github.com/lognormal/boomerang